# Getting NULL values while loading the Excel sheets data to SQL Server using SSIS

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I have to upload some Excel files using Excel to database using SSIS.

| date | code | extension | remarks |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021 | AA | FERST | CX NEED ASK |
| 2022 | AG22 | GERTS | EGG INFO REQ |
| 2021 | A011 | SETWEL | REVISIT |

This files contains on an average 6 records. While loading the files to SQL Server I am getting lots of null values and the Data Flow Task is not stopping until I forcefully stop it. SSIS is automatically reading the unfilled cells of Excel. I used multicast and conditional split to monitor and eliminate the null, I am getting the desired output but the Data Flow Task keeps on running and due to this I am unable to execute FOREACH LOOP CONTAINER. Please suggest how to I restrict the Excel preview to only rows that has data or how do I limit the records to be pushed to the database.

[image: Excel file preview]

[image: File]

Comment: Did the Excel file previously contain many more than six rows? Excel is exceedingly random about cleaning up deleted rows. e.g.: if you reopen the file in Excel and press Ctrl+End does it move the selection to the sixth row, or some (apparently) empty row much further on?

Comment: @AlwaysLearning its going uptill 1048574. How to solve this as i tried deleting the rows but on pressing Ctrl+End its again going to 1048574.